# Join on multiple tables from different db in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I decided to separate tables into different databases and now i can't make a join query on different tables
I added connectin property to each model in my project so now Account model has protected $connection = 'aniguru_users', Anime has protected $connection = 'aniguru' and List model has protected $connection = 'aniguru_lists'
Here the connection and config code:
config/databases.php file

```
        'aniguru' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
        
        'aniguru_users' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('SECOND_DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('SECOND_DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('SECOND_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('SECOND_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('SECOND_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'aniguru_lists' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('THIRD_DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('THIRD_DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('THIRD_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('THIRD_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('THIRD_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

.env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=aniguru
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=aniguru
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

SECOND_DB_CONNECTION=aniguru_users
SECOND_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
SECOND_DB_PORT=3306
SECOND_DB_DATABASE=aniguru
SECOND_DB_USERNAME=root
SECOND_DB_PASSWORD=

THIRD_DB_CONNECTION=aniguru_lists
THIRD_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
THIRD_DB_PORT=3306
THIRD_DB_DATABASE=aniguru
THIRD_DB_USERNAME=root
THIRD_DB_PASSWORD=
```

In Account model I'm trying to get the user list
Old code:

```
    public function getUserAnimeList($user, $list)
    {
        $tableName = new $this->lists[$list];
        return $this->lists[$list]::where('user', $user)->join('animes', $tableName->getTable().'.anime', '=', 'title')->select('animes.title', 'animes.poster')->get();
        
    }
```

New code:

```
public function getUserAnimeList($user, $list)
    {
        $animeModel = new Anime();
        $listModel = new $this->lists[$list];
    
        $animeTable = $animeModel->getTable();
        $listTable = $listModel->getTable();

        return $listModel::where('user', $user)
            ->join("aniguru.$animeTable as animes", "aniguru_lists.$listTable.anime", '=', "animes.title")
            ->select("animes.title", "animes.poster")
            ->get();
        
    }
```

On my new code i'm getting this error:SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'aniguru.allready_watched' doesn't exist
SELECT
`animes`.`title`,
`animes`.`poster`
FROM
`allready_watched`
INNER JOIN `aniguru`.`animes` AS `animes` ON `aniguru_lists`.`allready_watched`.`anime` = `animes`.`title`
WHERE
`USER` = test

I'll be thankfull for your attention and any help with this problem

Comment: You can join tables located in different databases by using their fully qualified names (including the db) but you cannot join tables using two or more distinct connections.

Comment: as @volkerschulz mentioned. You are using different connections. Joining over them is impossible.  You also shouldn't join like this, if it's even possible it's always using a memory join, which is slow and uses a lot of resources on your database server.

Comment: Thank you both. I changed .env file so now i have one connection for all db's and I used full table names to get data from them. Now everything works correctly.